# auto.arima residuals for more than one ts

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to write a function which gives the residuals of auto.arima to apply the Box-Ljung Test. I tried `lapply()` but I don't now how to get the residuals of each series using this.

```
library(fpp2)

#Make up some Time Series
dj1=dj
dj2=dj+2
dj3=dj+7


dataframe=cbind(dj1,dj2,dj3)
dataframe=as.data.frame(dataframe)


#Return calculation
Ret=diff(log(as.matrix(dataframe)),1)
Ret=as.data.frame(Ret)

AutoArima= lapply(Ret, function(x) auto.arima(x))
AutoArima
```

I would like to have a matrix/dataframe with 3 columns `dj1`, `dj2`, `dj3` and 291 rows (which contain the residuals of each column).

I am able to calculate residuals for a single time series, but not for each series when they are organized in a dataframe/matrix. I tried some other things but it gives: 
`Error in auto.arima(x) : 
 auto.arima can only handle univariate time series`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add those two lines to your code

```
res=lapply(AutoArima,function(x) x$residuals)
res0=do.call("cbind",res)
```

I think res0 is what you look for

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should accept Antonis answer, not mine if his answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your honest comment. In any case I reproduced your answer as well which is absolutely correct.  I also learned fuction `resid` that I was not aware of .

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
library(purrr) 
df = map_df(AutoArima[1:ncol(Ret)],resid)
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. But my the dataset above is just an example. My real datasat has a lot more columns. So I am searching for a more efficient solution

Comment: In that case, this might help `library(purrr)`   
`df = map_df(AutoArima[1:ncol(Ret)],resid) %>% data.matrix()
`